# Unable to execute powershell cmd file

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to execute powershell cmd file, but I received this error message:

```
System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException: 'Cannot find path 
'C:\Users\HP\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XVPNC\XVPNC\scripts\HotelMode.cmd' 
because it does not exist.'
```

But I am completely sure that it EXISTS!
What can I do now? Or where could be a mistake, please?

Here is my code:
(NOTE: even if i change path not to contain white spaces, it behaves identically!)

```
String scriptfilepath2 = "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\XVPNC\\XVPNC\\scripts\\HotelMode.cmd";
            Runspace space = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            space.Open();
            space.SessionStateProxy.Path.SetLocation(scriptfilepath2);
            Pipeline pipeline = space.CreatePipeline();
            var cresult = pipeline.Invoke();
            space.Close();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, i changed path to  "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\HotelMode-PB\\HotelMode.cmd"

And it does not work too. So this is not about white spaces i guess.

Comment: could it be possible that the user doesn't have permission?

Comment: oh, maybe yes. I need to run it as administrator.

Comment: Thing to keep in mind too: hierarchy of things inside VS solution does not always represent the directory structure in file system.

Comment: How is this a PowerShell issue?

Comment: You can not `SetLocation` to file. It need to be directory.